# Setting a property on a custom object through Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a custom UITableViewController subclass which I use in two places in a nib file. What should I do if I want the two instances to have slightly different behavior? Of course in the code I can select one kind of behavior or the other based on the value of a BOOL, but how do I set that BOOL from Interface Builder, without having to write an Interface Builder plugin?

Comment: Why can't you do it in code? I don't even bother using IB for iphone, there's not much point for simple UI's for iPhone apps.

Answer (score 8):

As of Xcode 6 there is a new way doing this. You can now give your view properties the attribute IBInspectable and then you can edit those properties in IB as you would with and standard view.

So for example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable BOOL
```

More details (also for the new attribute IBDesignable) in Apples documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html

Answer (score 3):

"User Defined Runtime Attributes" in the Identity inspector is probably what you're looking for. This [seems to be new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980251/user-defined-runtime-attributes-in-ib-for-iphone-not-working) as of Xcode 4.2.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be much (any?) documentation about this feature on the Apple Developer site. I was able to use it for a simple property set.

Answer (score 2):

So far as I know, you can't set parameters in IB without writing an IB Plugin.

That said, you have two other options.

If it is as simple as a single BOOL, you're probably best off making it a property of the `MyCustomViewController` class and set it in code after you init:

```
customViewController = [[MyCustomViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController" bundle:nil];
[customViewController setFunky:YES];
```

The other option is to create a protocol for a `MyCustomViewDelegate`.  If you're not familiar with protocols, your header would look like this:

```
@class MyCustomViewController;

@protocol MyCustomViewDelegate
@required
-(BOOL)customViewShouldBeFunky:(MyCustomViewController*)customView;
@end

@interface MyCustomViewController : UIViewController {
  NSObject<MyCustomViewDelegate>  *delegate;
}
@property (readwrite, retain) IBOutlet NSObject<MyCustomViewDelegate> *delegate;
@end
```

Since it is an `IBOutlet`, you can wire up the delegate like any other delegate in Interface Builder.

Then call `[delegate customViewShouldBeFunky:self]` when you need to determine how your view should behave.

Answer (score 0):

Have two subclasses is probably easier, and will be easier to document.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of overriding properties and setting them in custom classes, this may help. The property code will work before awakeFromNib is called. So you may decide what you have to do based on the user's decision right in awakeFromNib.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31094561/1699210

Comment: Hi Umair, your last two answers are pointing to a deleted answer, I think you are tooking for this link? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31094561/1699210. Nevertheless, as the are standing they might get removed as link only answer, you should flesh them out. In general this would be preferably a comment (I know you can't below 50 rep)