# User Defined Runtime Attributes in IB for iPhone not working

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have a weird problem.

I am trying to setup User Defined Runtime Attribute in the IB. As shown below I setup a NSString **statID** attribute in my viewController and wanted to give it a test value **00000** in IB

[image: User Defined Runtime Attributes]

When I compile that I get this error when building: "User defined runtime attributes on Mac OS X versions prior to 10.6"

I know I can set up user defined attributes in iOS from the iOS docs found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/ObjectAttributes/ObjectAttributes.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH20-SW1) go down to section: "Configuring Runtime Attributes for Custom Objects"

Any idea why it is giving me the error?

Comment: I realize your problem is pretty specific, but here's a generic link to help the rest of us: http://twoshotsofcocoa.com/?p=70

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I got an answer.

So here it goes.

I am using the beta version of XCode 4. As it is a beta versions it has errors, one of them is displaying "User Defined Runtime Attributes" window in an IB.
The error **"User defined runtime attributes on Mac OS X versions prior to 10.6"** informs you that **"User Defined Runtime Attributes"** option is **only** availabe **for OS X** apps and not for iOS.

It dissapoints me but at least I don't have to wonder why is it not working.

Comment: I had a similar problem working on a Mac OS X application. Modifying the version of the XIB to Xcode 4.2 solved the problem for me. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992079/ignore-attribute-unavailable-warning-in-xcode4

Comment: Antonio, that was the answer to my problem.  You should make it an answer so we can up-vote it!

Answer (score 26):

User defined runtime attributes are available now in XCode 4.2. However it requires:

- Compiling with iOS 5.0.
- Setting the .xib version attribute to 4.2
- Running in a simulator or device with iOS 5.0. Older version won't work.

Comment: Extra tip to set .xib version attribute: in the XCode Utilities view (pane at right), open the File inspector with the button at the top of the pane, and under Interface Builder Document, for the Development dropdown menu, select an XCode version 4.2+.

Answer (score 1):

i'm going to answer this anew, because i think @AntonioVieiro's comment is so helpful, and because it can be made to work.

the error i was seeing was: "Size type user defined runtime attributes with Xcode versions prior to 4.3".  i had ignored it for a while, because things ran despite the diagnostic.  but it always bugged me that i am running Xcode 4.3.2 and would be getting this error.

the link [ignore attribute unavailable warning in Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992079/ignore-attribute-unavailable-warning-in-xcode4) points to the solution that gets rid of the errors:  it's step by step, and very useful.  and it does allow the use of user defined runtime attributes now in iOS .