# Warning:Attribute Unavailable

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3

Does anyone know, how to remove this warning from Xcode 4.3 and above
**Attributed Title on iOS versions prior to 6.0**

[image]

Edited: If I set the deployment target as 6.0 then I don't see this warning.

**give proper reason before down voting.Is this not a valid question**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on your xib file. On the properties you will see the following section:

[image]

Where it says "Development" change that to Interface Builder 6.0 and you should no longer receive those warnings.

Follow this link for more info [Ignore "Attribute Unavailable"-Warning in Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992079/ignore-attribute-unavailable-warning-in-xcode4)

Comment: you mean to say at, we can't remove this warning if deployment target is 5.0

Answer (score 2):

Well, if your Deployment Target is set to an iOS version lower than 6.0 you won't get rid of this warning. Either you don't use this attribute, or you switch the deployment traget to iOS 6.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. warning is generated for iOS 5.0