# User Defined Runtime Attributes causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS from xib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using a custom class for my UIViews, which I am controlling some configuration by using User Defined Runtime Attributes.  This works fine when using storyboards, but when I use the same technique within a xib, my custom view class generates a bad access when trying to read the attribute.

As with [User Defined Runtime Attributes in IB for iPhone not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980251/user-defined-runtime-attributes-in-ib-for-iphone-not-working) I had to set the .xib IB version to 4.2 so it would compile.  Is this just not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the other post, it's not supported by iOS. Maybe it is with iOS 5's storyboards, but it doesn't seem to be for xibs.

Comment: Yeah, that is my suspicion too :(