# Set UIButton Layer Border Width and Color in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder, xcode6

Can I use IB_DESIGNABLE and/or IBInspectable to set layer.borderWidth and layer.borderColor in Interface Builder? I am currently creating my button in code but I'd like to be able to set all of this in IB but I'm not sure if these properties can be set that way in Xcode 6. I'd like to make this an IBOutlet instead of having all of this set in code. Here is my button code now.

```
directions = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
directions.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
directions.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:20.0];
[directions setTitle:@"Directions" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[directions setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
directions.frame = CGRectMake(20, 178, 70, 70);
directions.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
directions.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
directions.clipsToBounds = YES;
directions.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[directions addTarget:self action:@selector(getDirections:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:directions];
```

[image]

I set these values as suggested and the border is never shown in the simulator.
EDIT: I found out why the border wasn't showing up when setting these values in IB. The border color is a CGColor so I had to set it in code.

[image]

Answer (score 35):

Actually you can set some properties of a view's layer through interface builder. I know that I can set a layer's borderWidth and cornerRadius through xcode. borderColor doesn't work, probably because the layer wants a CGColor instead of a UIColor.

You might have to use Strings instead of numbers, but it works!

[image]

But you can use categories to proxy properties such as layer.borderColor. (From the [ConventionalC](https://github.com/ConventionalC/ConventionalC/blob/develop/ios/CALayer+XibConfiguration.h) CocoaPod)

**CALayer+XibConfiguration.h:**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CALayer(XibConfiguration)

// This assigns a CGColor to borderColor.
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIColor* borderUIColor;

@end
```

**CALayer+XibConfiguration.m:**

```
#import "CALayer+XibConfiguration.h"

@implementation CALayer(XibConfiguration)

-(void)setBorderUIColor:(UIColor*)color
{
    self.borderColor = color.CGColor;
}

-(UIColor*)borderUIColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithCGColor:self.borderColor];
}

@end
```

[image: Interface Builder]

The result will be apparent during runtime, not in Xcode.

Comment: For others coming across this, if you want the swift version, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27986696/130556

Comment: Looks like you can set the cornerRadius with a Number value in the User Defined Runtime Attributes as of Xcode 7.3.

Comment: how to setup this porxy

Comment: It's simple. Make a class CALayer+XibConfiguration.h write the above code in that class. That's set. You can now use it interface builder in runtime attributes.

Answer (score 5):

You can set most of those in the interface builder adding runtime attributes to the elements:
[image]

For layer.borderWidth = 2.0f; would be:

Select the button and add a new attribute

keypath : layer.borderWidth

type: Number
Value 2

These changes will not be visible inside the interface builder, only at runtime

Comment: Thanks. That helps but I'm wanting to know about using IBInspectable and IB_DESIGNABLE so that the effects can be seen in IB.

Comment: You also have to set up the borderColor to see the border

Comment: See the update to my question. I have set borderColor.

Answer (score 5):

yes u can
in the right side click on identity inspector, u will find like this
[image]

click `+` in `User Defined Runtime Attributes`

select `keypath` and edit it

write the code like this

`layer.cornerRadius` and in `Type` change the type to `number` and set ur required value like this

[image]

u can also change text colors and so many.

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks. That helps but I'm wanting to know about using IBInspectable and IB_DESIGNABLE so that the effects can be seen in IB.

Comment: And I tried this just now and the border does not appear.

Comment: you have to set `[button.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];`

Comment: I just tried setting that and the border still  does not show