# How to show border of a button in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am creating user interface for app in storyboard, but I can not find where I can set the border for a button to be visible in storyboard. How do I set the border of a button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set UIButton Layer Border Width and Color in Interface Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161429/set-uibutton-layer-border-width-and-color-in-interface-builder)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select Xcode -> Open Editor menu -> Canvas -> Show Bounds Rectangles

[image]

Note that all views will have borders and only be visible in storyboard(design time).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to visualize the button, you could check this after setting the constraints of the Button:

[image: update thet frame]

Or, by setting the style of the `UIButton`:

[image: set the style of the UIButton]

If none of above meet your requirements, you have to set the border of the button in the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

myButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
```