# How do I use @IBInspectable with bar button items?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have added an extension like this:

```
extension UINavigationController { 
    @IBInspectable var hideLeftItem: Bool {
        get { return self.hideLeftItem }
        set {
              self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
            }
        }
}
```

But it doesn't work when I set it in the `identity inspector`. I have tried to set it in the `identity inspector` both in the `navigation controller` and the `navigation bar` as well as the `navigation item` itself (but then extending the item instead). If I just set the code straight in `viewDidLoad` it works, but I don't want that. What am I missing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906855/can-you-add-ibdesignable-properties-to-uiview-using-categories-extensions It doesn't work for extensions

Comment: @VitaliiShvetsov, that answer was 5 years ago, it is supposed to work with extensions these days.

Comment: Where am I supposed to set it? In the navigation controller?

Comment: Is your goal to hide the "Back" button, without needing to add code in each view controller?