# How to set border color of UIView at runtime

Tags: ios, iphone, colors, frame

I have required to set border color `UIView` using User Defined Runtime Attributes`in identity inspector. By default Color is`BlackColor`. If any constraints is available in iOS then tell me.

Comment: what do you mean by runtime constraints?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792238/uiviews-border-color-in-interface-builder-doesnt-work

Answer (score 3):

you can set border color like,

```
yourView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor; 
yourView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0; //you have to give width to make border visible
```

**Update according to comment :**

you can set runtime attributes for view like below screenshot,

[image]

But it will display black border because `layer uses cgcolor` and you can't get cgcolor reference in interface builder. so you can't set layer color directly as runtime attribute. It's better to set from code as i have mentioned above.

If you hardly want to set color from runtime attribute only then you can try [Peter Deweese's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301256/is-it-possible-to-set-uiview-border-properties-from-interface-builder/17993890#17993890).

Comment: But I have required to add borderColor using Runtime Constraints. That's not properly answers for me.

Comment: means? what you want exactly ? explain it because i am not getting your need!

Comment: In XCode -> Attribute Inspector -> User Defined Runtime Attributes -> here we can also set Constraints for the view.

Comment: Its **User Defined Runtime Attributes**

Comment: There are no option available in `attribute inspector` i think. I think you are saying about `user define run time attribute` from `identity inspector`. is it so ?

Comment: check my update in answer

Answer (score 3):

This will work -

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    ...
    //Add a Your Color border 
    view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f; //make border 1px thick
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this code, `ViewController.h`

declare `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *searchView;` In `ViewController.m`.

`viewDidLoad` Method:

```
    searchView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
    searchView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    searchView.layer.borderWidth = 0.8f;
    searchView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    searchView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f;
    searchView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
    searchView.layer.shadowOffset =CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f);
```

Comment: But I have required to add borderColor using Runtime Constraints. That's not properly answers for me.

Comment: see the link, its clearly showed you need, https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/05/30/xcode-runtime-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

try this code it will help you:

```
yourViewNAme.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    yourViewNAme.layer.borderColor = [UIColor DesiredColour].CGColor;
```

Comment: But I have required to add borderColor using Runtime Constraints. That's not properly answers for me.