# Runtime attributes border color

Tags: ios, button, runtime, border

I use `defined runtime attributes` in button.

```
layer.cornerRadius
layer.masksToBounds
layer.borderWidth
```

And I want to paint my border in green colour. But my code doesn’t work:

```
layer.borderUIColor
```

Borders have black colour. How to paint border in colour with runtime attributes?

[image]

Comment: are you sure for you this line of code?
layer.borderUIColor is correct property for layer border color?

May be this will be layer.borderColor.

Comment: If i use `layer.borderColor` my border has disappeared

Comment: because from IB we can only assign UIColor, we can't assign CGColor. You must have to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, you are using wrong attribute.The, correct attribute is `layer.borderColor`.
But again it will not work because it is type of CGColor and from IB we can only assign UIColor, we can't assign CGColor.

Eihter you can simply do it programaticlly.

Or

You can create extension with type CGColor.

Comment: If i use `layer.borderColor` my border has disappeared

Comment: Thanks! It is work for me. Do I need to save this `layer.masksToBounds` or remove it?

Comment: You can set it to true.

Answer (score 5):

Order also matters for runtime attributes.
I use following and it worked for me:
[image]

Comment: !    work for me.......but kindly share the code for easy to use

Comment: This is used in Storyboard, code not written in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear for this to work

Comment: Where do you get that dark User Defined Runtime Attributes window from?

Comment: @AlexZavatone it's background color set for entire Xcode not only for User defined attributes, if you haven't set dark mode for Xcode, it will be white by default in Xcode

Comment: Oh, you just have dark mode on in the Storyboard.  I thought this was a popup.  Thanks.  If you are going to use borderUIColor, you need a computed property to return a cgColor.  That prop doesn't exist on its own.

Comment: This is the answer that creatively solved the problem without requiring a computed property.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46215487/1058199

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 13.4, MacOS 12.4, 07082022

This is the answer that creatively solved the problem without requiring a computed property. It works with `layer.borderColor` in the `User Defined Runtime Attributes` to add a border color to any, UIView.

[Łukasz-kalbarczykenter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8608170/%C5%81ukasz-kalbarczyk)
http://stackoverflow.com/a/46215487/1058199

It traps the setting of each runtime attribute and traps for the key name of `borderColor`.  If we have a match, it returns the cgColor value for
borderColor from the supplied UIColor.

Here is my updated answer from the work of [Łukasz-kalbarczykenter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8608170/%C5%81ukasz-kalbarczyk)

All I changed was set the extension to CALayer from UIView and made sure to use self.border

```
import UIKit

extension CALayer {
    open override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        guard key == "borderColor", let color = value as? UIColor else {
            super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
            return
        }
        
        self.borderColor = color.cgColor
    }
}
```

Next, in the storyboard, just select your UIView, press command option 4 and just add `layer.borderColor` as your desired UIColor to the User Defined Runtime Attributes.  Then run your app and it should work!

Answer (score -1):

you should use : layer.borderColor and set layer.masksToBounds = false

Answer (score -1):

This will work for sure.

you can manage this through storyborad as you are doing but you are passing the wrong key here. it should be

```
    layer.borderColorFromUIColor
```